# error cs0016 could not write to output file needlicense.cshtml access is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Installation of ASP.NET application goes through fine. But launching it after installation causes this error in browser.

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0016: Could not write to output file
'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\
d09d1fc5\8ea09859\App_Web_needlicense.cshtml.639c3968.h6teml6g.dll' -- 'Access is denied.'
```

I have seen many questions on this error, but this is on a different dll. Fixes provided in similar errors doesnt seem to work for me. Hence, I thought of checking this particular error here.

I am hopeful of finding a perfect answer here. Thanks.